# What's the best way to translate a html file in Xamarin Ios

Tags: html, xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios, resx

I am currently at a dead end on one of the projects I am working on.
I'm working on the translation of an application in Xamarin Ios, at the moment
the entire application can be translated and the language of the application can be changed directly via the app.

But this application also has Tutorials pages that explain in a few words what is the purpose of this feature.

These pages are in html and have a relatively simplistic content that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content-block">
            <p>Use this page to add a new friend</p>
            <p>It could be a good idea to give him a pseudo</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

These pages should be translated on the fly when the user
decides to change the language of the application.

Currently the entire application could be translated into several languages ​​except these html pages, simply because I have no idea what's the best  way to do it.
I didn't find any information or documentation about this (I'm pretty sure that's because I'm using Xamarin Ios).

I am looking for a way to fill my html file with the contents of my resx files in which I would put the content html pages.

1 - I will have to save Html tags in my resx files if I decide to write `<strong> this word </ strong>`, which does not seem to me very practical and will oblige me to record every sentence and / or word that stands between specific tag ?

2 - How can I do this binding between my html file and my resx file? To get something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content-block">
            <p> [contentFromMyResxFile] </p>
            <p> [AnotherContentFromMyResxFile] </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

content being loaded directly from my resx file and so could adapt to the language of the application.

Comment: why don't you just save multiple localized copies of the HTML file and load the appropriate one based on the language setting?

Comment: I would go with the way Jason described... but if you really want to, you could convert those html files to razor templates : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/razor-html-templates/#what-is-razor

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing but I think this solution is pretty redundant I have almost 10 files and 5 languages for instance...

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm going to take a look about Razor Templates, thx !